# onopen "unknown sheet name" error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is my first foray into Google scripts and JavaScript (I'm a reformed VBAer). But my  simple code is proving hard to get to work.

I have a couple of routines I want to run on open. They run OK when the sheet is already open, but not on opening. I am familiar with the triggers and I've set up immediate error messages.

Here is one to delete some columns if the data in the header precedes today -- it works fine if the sheet is already open.

```
function DeletePastDays(){
  var sheet  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var today = new Date();
  today = rounddownday(today);
  var date = sheet.getRange(1,4).getValue();
  while(date < today){
  sheet.deleteColumn(4);
  var date = sheet.getRange(1, 4).getValue();
  }
}
```

The error message is:
Unknown sheet name (line 6) 
(which is the line that defines the variable date, based on the sheet that's defined with getActiveSheet).

Other routines all apparently fail the same way, because it doesn't recognize the sheet, even though they all run OK from the open sheet.

Wonder if I have to call the sheet by name because it isn't yet really open? Though other code I have seen doesn't seem to go to that trouble. Have tried a bunch of things for several hours, but finally have to admit I need help! Thank you.

Comment: The first line needs to have the active spreadsheet, something like: `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();`. The second line needs to change to this: `var sheet  = ss.getActiveSheet();`. Good luck.

Comment: Jacob, Thank you for the suggestion. Still works from within the sheet, but not on open. Have tried both renaming the function onOpen, and adding an on Open trigger to the function without renaming it. Here is the new code:function DeletePastDays(){
  var ss  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var today = new Date();
  today = rounddownday(today);
  var date = sheet.getRange(1,4).getValue();
  while(date < today){
  sheet.deleteColumn(4);
  var date = sheet.getRange(1, 4).getValue();
  }
}

Comment: See following example code: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/36352/29140

Comment: Can you share this sheet with us?

Comment: sorry for delay - I omitted to get email updates on replies. You can probably detect I am new here. The sheet is here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AuY9YR4A4rCGdHRRZ1AxUjRwZGZYVlhSdFRSamZwaFE#gid=17

Comment: Meantime I will go look at your link. Course, you can;t see the code from that link. do you want me to share some other way?

Comment: Jacob - your example has another variation I hadn't yet used; getActive followed by getActiveSheet. (I have hitherto used getActiveSheet with and without getActiveSpreadsheet -- both of which I have seen used elsewhere). But like the others, this works if I call it from an open sheet, but not on open.

Comment: Shall we continue on g+: here's my profile: https://plus.google.com/u/1/115210795692612339592/about